# Why am I getting a "conversion to ‘short unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value" warning when subtracting two unsigned shorts

Tags: c

I am getting this warning

```
warning: conversion to ‘short unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
unsigned short spaceEmpty = 10 - spaceFilled;
```

from these lines of code

```
unsigned short spaceFilled = num_items(aisle, j);
unsigned short spaceEmpty = 10 - spaceFilled;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
num_items returns an unsigned short, and spaceFilled initialized properly.

So why is performing an arithmetic operation in spaceEmpty giving me a warning?

Comment: "when subtracting two unsigned shorts" is off.  `10` is not an `unsigned short`.  It is an `int`.  Try `spaceEmpty = (unsigned char) (10u - spaceFilled;)` or `(10u - spaceFilled) & USHRT_MAX` to avoid casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `10 - spaceFilled` has type `int` due to [arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) of the operands taking place before doing the arithmetic.

Then you assign this `int` to `unsigned short`, which leads to the warning.

There are two parts that influence the final type:

- `10` literal is of type `int`. So the operation will take on types of at least that size
- `spaceFilled`, being smaller than `int`, gets promoted to at least `int`.

So even if you replace `10` with `(unsigned short)10`, you'll still get promotion of the operands to `int`.

Comment: Does that mean you'll get a warning whenever you assign the result of an arithmetic operation to a `short`? Seems like a pretty useless warning then.

Comment: So I casted (10 - spaceFilled) to an unsigned short and I stopped getting the warning. Thanks!

Comment: @scy17 you may want to accept an answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @interjay actually, not _quite_ useless: e.g. `(short)60000*(short)60000` would generate a similar warning, and the _presence_ of this warning will at least hint to the undefined behavior you'll get due to signed arithmetic overflow (multiplying two `int`s not fitting into an `int`). Not directly though, and the programmer might not get it, but still.

Comment: You'd get the same undefined behavior by overflowing in an arithmetic operation between two `int`s (and assigning into an `int`), but no warning then. Besides, warning on any operation that has a small chance of going wrong seems pointless when there isn't a safer way to perform that operation.

Comment: Your compiler is showing you the flag that enables this warning. You can disable it with `-Wno-conversion`

Comment: @interjay in the case of `int`*`int` you should already have paid attention. But (my example in the comment was no good: it should have been `unsigned short` on both sides) if you multiply `(unsigned short)60000` by itself, you'd expect that, being unsigned, it should obey the modular arithmetic rules. Alas, it doesn't, because the operands get promoted to a `signed int`, which undefines the arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`10` is an integer constant of type `int`. If you do arithmetic operations with values of different types, the value with the type of the smaller representation is promoted to the type of the value with the greater representation.

Note: A cast means a conversion too so if you explicitly cast one of the operand values the promotion rule still applies.

For example, `(unsigned short) 10 + (unsigned short) 10` still gains a value of type `int`, too.

So in:

```
10 - spaceFilled;
```

`spaceFilled` gets promoted to an `int` before the subtraction.

The result `int` value is assigned to `spaceEmpty` of type `unsigned short`. There happens a conversion from `int` to `unsigned short` here.

This is what the warnings warns you about as the result value in `spaceEmpty` can be different than expected due to the conversion.

Comment: `(unsigned short)10 - spaceFilled` will yield the same warning.

Comment: The integer promotions make your first paragraph misleading. `(signed char)1 + (unsigned short)2` is an `int` (under normal circumstances).

Comment: @PaulHankin even `(unsigned short)1+(unsigned short)1` is an `int`.

Comment: @Ruslan it may be `unsigned int` if `short` and `int` are the same size :)

Comment: @Ruslan Tried to cover it in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulHankin It's a little complicated to describe all of the possibilities for the promotion rule in a simple manner, but I tried. Is it better now or still misleading?